# Ember's computed property @each doesn't fire when filtered array is at top level

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to setup computed property based on filtered value. The problem is that @each supports only 1 level nesting and doesn't work on top level.

From official guide:

> Note that @each only works one level deep. You cannot use nested forms like todos.@each.owner.name or todos.@each.owner.@each.name.

So neither this

```
computedProperty: function() {
    return this.get('context').filterProperty('selected', true);
}.property('@each.selected');
```

or this

```
computedProperty: function() {
    return this.get('context').filterProperty('selected', true)[0];
}.property('context.@each.selected')
```

don't work (computed property is not fired once `context` is changed).

`context` is passed in a `Ember.ContainerView` instantiation:

```
childViews: function() {
return [
  App.ReportNavigationFilterView.create({
    filterType:   'base',
    filterColor:  'orange',
    context:      this.get('controller.model.base')
    //context:      Ember.computed.alias('controller.model.base')
  }),
  App.ReportNavigationFilterView.create({
    filterType:   'sector',
    filterColor:  'green',
    context:      this.get('controller.model.sector')
  }),
  App.ReportNavigationFilterView.create({
    filterType:   'topic',
    filterColor:  'yellow',
    context:      this.get('controller.model.topic')
  }),
  App.ReportNavigationFilterView.create({
    filterType:   'answer',
    filterColor:  'red',
    context:      this.get('controller.model.answer')
  })
];
}.property()
```

Any suggestions on how can I updated computedProperty when context is changed?

```
context = [ {selected: true}, {selected: false}, ...]
```

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up switch from `Ember.ContainerView` to `Ember.CollectionView`, where the following works:

```
computedProperty: function() {
   return this.get('context').filterProperty('selected', true)[0];
}.property('content.@each.selected')
```